# Is the Grothendieck topology equivalent to its Singleton Grothendieck topology?

Tags: ct.category-theory, sheaf-theory, grothendieck-topology

I'm using the definition of a Grothendieck topology in Angelo Vistoli’s 2007 [*Notes on Grothendieck topologies,
fibered categories
and descent theory*](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0412512.pdf) and I found on nLab about [superextensive site](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/superextensive+site), that with coproducts we can create a the Singleton Grothendieck topology, by replacing a covering family $\{U_i\rightarrow U\}_{i\in I}$ from $\mathcal{T}$ with the single map $\coprod_{i\in I}U_i\rightarrow U $. These single maps form a new grothendieck topology, the singleton grothendieck topology $\mathcal{T}_S$ and I asked myself if these two grothendieck topologies are equivalent?

> **Background:**
>
> *Refinement:*
> Let $C$ be a category, $\{U_i\xrightarrow{\phi_i} U\}_{i\in I}$ a set of arrows. A refinement $\{Va\xrightarrow{\psi_a} U\}_{a\in A}$ is a set of arrows such that for each index $a\in A$ there is some index $i\in I$ such that $V_a\xrightarrow{\psi_a} U$ factors through
> $U_i\xrightarrow{\phi_i} U$.
>
> *Subordinate Grothendieck Topology:*
> Let $C$ be a category, $\mathcal{T}$ and $\mathcal{T'}$ two topologies on $C$. We say that $\mathcal{T}$ is subordinate to $\mathcal{T'}$, and write $\mathcal{T}\prec\mathcal{T'}$, if every covering in $\mathcal{T}$ has a
> refinement that is a covering in $\mathcal{T'}$. If $\mathcal{T}\prec\mathcal{T'}$ and $\mathcal{T'}\prec\mathcal{T}$, we say that $\mathcal{T}$ and $\mathcal{T'}$ are equivalent, and write $\mathcal{T}\equiv\mathcal{T'}$.

So with that background in mind I tried to prove that $\mathcal{T}\equiv\mathcal{T}_S$.

First $\mathcal{T}_S\prec\mathcal{T}$: Let $\{U_i\xrightarrow{\phi_i} U\}_{i\in I}$ be a covering from $\mathcal{T}$ and $\coprod_{i\in I}U_i\xrightarrow{\phi} U$ a covering from $\mathcal{T}_S$. With the injections $\{U_i\xrightarrow{\psi_i}\coprod_{i\in I}U_i\}_{i\in I}$ of the coproduct we get for every $i\in I$ a morphism $\psi_i$ such that $U_i\xrightarrow{\phi_i} U$ factors through $\coprod_{i\in I}U_i\xrightarrow{\phi} U$ or else $\phi_i=\phi\circ\psi_i$. So with that $\{U_i\xrightarrow{\phi_i} U\}_{i\in I}$ is a refinement of $\coprod_{i\in I}U_i\xrightarrow{\phi} U$ and hence $\mathcal{T}_S\prec\mathcal{T}$.

But now I'm stuck with $\mathcal{T}\prec\mathcal{T}_S$. Is that even possible? In the post [Why are non-singleton covering families often ignored?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/9705/why-are-non-singleton-covering-families-often-ignored) I got the feeling, that these grothendieck topologies are not equivalent because they don't generate the same sieves or notion of sheaves. But I'm not sure if I got that right, so that is why I have the following question:

**Question:** Are $\mathcal{T}$ and $\mathcal{T}_S$ equivalent? If yes, how do you prove $\mathcal{T}\prec\mathcal{T}_S$?

Comment: I think you need some hypotheses on $C$ to ensure that these are equivalent.

Comment: The original topology is generated by the singleton topology _together with the extensive topology_. Consider the covering $\{U,V\}$ of the object $U\amalg V$ (and neither of $U,V$ initial. Ask yourself: can there be a singleton covering of $U\amalg V$ that refines $\{U,V\}$? Recall that as $C$ is extensive, your covering map $Y\to U\amalg V$ is isomorphic (in the slice) to a coproduct of maps: $Y_U\amalg Y_V \to U\amalg V$. You'd need to find either a morphism $Y_U\amalg Y_V\to U$ or a morphism $Y_U\amalg Y_V \to V$ that's a lift of the cover....

Comment: You can go as trivial as taking the category $C=\mathbf{Set}$, $U=V =1$, so that $U\amalg V \simeq \{0,1\}$. Then a singleton covering family is a surjective function $Y\to \{0,1\}$, and the covering family $\{\{0\},\{1\}\}$ of $\{0,1\}$ cannot be refined by any singleton cover.

Comment: So does that mean, that in general the singleton topology and original topology are not equivalent, but if the category $C$ is extensive than they are equivalent?

Comment: @MusterMaxfrau No, they are basically never equivalent. You need to add disjoint unions, as David says.