# Non-invertible map between principal bundles only locally trivial in a supercanonical Grothendieck topology?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ct.category-theory, stacks, principal-bundles, sites

It is a truth universally acknowledged that a map between principal bundles must be in want of an inverse.

However, the construction of said inverse in the context of a more general site $(S,J)$ proceeds by constructing an inverse $J$-locally (which exists because maps all trivial bundles are isomorphisms), and then using a descent property. It follows from general facts about [$G$-torsors in a slice category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/torsor#definition) (i.e. principal bundles without the assumption of local triviality) that a map of $G$-torsors is an isomorphism (of $G$-torsors) if and only if it is an isomorphism in the slice category alone.

So the question can be reduced to looking at the underlying map of $G$-bundles $\phi\colon P\to Q$ in the slice category $S/X$ (for $p\colon P\to X$, $q\colon Q\to X$ the projection maps). Since there are $J$-local trivialisations of $P$ and $Q$, which can wlog be taken to be over the same $J$-cover $\{j_{\alpha}\colon U_\alpha \to X\}_{\alpha\in I}$, the pullback of $\phi$ along $j_\alpha$ is an isomorphism in $S/U_\alpha$. Let $\psi_\alpha$ be the inverse of $j_\alpha^*\phi$, for each $\alpha\in I$.

Moreover, this family of isomorphisms can be promoted to be an isomorphism of [descent data](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/026B) for the codomain fibration, for the cover $\{j_{\alpha}\colon U_\alpha \to X\}_{\alpha\in I}$, for the morphism arising from pulling back $\phi$. And so here we get to the point: according to the question [Sites which are stacks over themselves](https://mathoverflow.net/q/9636/4177), the codomain fibration of a site $(S,J)$ is a prestack on that site (i.e. the hom-presheaves are sheaves) iff the (pre-)topology is subcanonical.

So, if our starting site is subcanonical we can use the prestack property to glue together the inverses defined over each $U_\alpha$ to get an inverse to $\phi$. However, what if our topology is something like the [h topology](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0ETQ) on the category of schemes? This is very much not subcanonical—it is, rather, *supercanonical* (see eg [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H_topology#Examples)).

Clearly, asking that we have that the codomain fibration is a prestack is slightly more than we need; asking that the comparison functor to the category of descent data is merely conservative (as opposed to fully faithful) is enough. And, even then, in the case of maps between principal bundles, everything is just a bit nicer than arbitrary objects in a slice category.

So, I'm wondering if there are principal bundles in, say, the category of schemes that are only locally trivial along an h-covering that is not a cover for the canonical topology, and a morphism between them that is *not* an isomorphism. Or any other site one can think of, for that matter.

Or, like in Austen, does the map in the end get the inverse, even if it wasn't looking for one?

Comment: One could also consider the [V topology](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0ETA) in place of the h topology (I misplaced my reference for that but I re-found it now: https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0ETA#comment-5642)

Comment: Are you interested in "real" examples, or contrived ones? e.g. if $f : A \to B$ is any noninvertible mono that we declare to be a singleton covering family, then $f$ is also a map of principal bundles on $B$ for the trivial group that does not have an inverse. (But after sheafififcation, it will have an inverse.)

Comment: @ReidBarton a real example! For the trivial group, every principal bundle is trivial (i.e. the projection map is an isomorphism), so I don't really understand what you mean by your contrived example. And by "real" example, ideally one for a known, named topology and a nontrivial group.

Comment: In my example $f$ is a principal bundle because it becomes trivial (an isomorphism) after pulling back along a cover, namely $f$ itself.

Comment: @Reid oh, I think I see. But I'll take that as a proof of concept, before a natural example using a known topology turns up.

Comment: The h-topology contains noninvertible monic coverings, e.g. if $X$ is a non-reduced Noetherian scheme, then $X_{\text{red}} \to X$ is an h-cover \[Tag [0ETW](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0ETW)\], and $X_{\text{red}} \to X$ is monic as it is a closed immersion

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn thanks! Now we just need to cook up an example involving a nontrivial group. Perhaps even taking $X_{\text{red}} \times G \to X$ and $X\times G\to X$? Much better would be an example where the latter was in fact nontrivial, but then eg restricted along $X_{\text{red}} \hookrightarrow X$ became a product (here I don't mean in the sense of being locally trivial in the h-topology, just outright)