# Question regarding 2-mathematics: Can you stackify a 2-functor without prestackifying it first?

Tags: stacks, 2-categories

Let $C$ be a site and $CAT$ the 2-category of categories. Given a contravariant 2-functor $A:C\rightarrow CAT$, we can of course consider the associated stack. This is done by first considering the associated prestack, denoted by $\hat{A}$, (i.e. sheafifying the hom) and then considering $2$-$lim_\mathfrak{U}Des(\mathfrak{U},\hat{A})$, the descent data of $\hat{A}$ with respect to the covering $\mathfrak{U}$.

EDIT: My question is, could we stackify $A$ purely with the descent data? In other words, define $A'(U):=2$-$lim_\mathfrak{U}(Des(\mathfrak{U},A))$,
$A''(U):=2$-$lim_\mathfrak{U}(Des(\mathfrak{U},A'))$ and
$A'''(U):=2$-$lim_\mathfrak{U}(Des(\mathfrak{U},A''))$.

Would $A'''$ be equivalent to the associated stack of $A$?.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is already not working with sheaficiation: if you try to sheafify directl a non separated sheaf this does not neccearly gives a sheaf, but a separated presheaf and you have to go to the process twice to abtain the sheafification.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But then, what about doing the descant data twice, or probably 3 times, i.e. defined $A''(U):=2$-$lim_{\mathfrak{U}}(Des(\mathfrak{U},A'))$ and then again $A'''$. Would that work?

Comment: I don't Know, but I'm sure somebody will. Maybe you should consider editing your question if it is what you want to know ?

Comment: This seems to be a folklore result. It is alluded to in [_Higher topos theory_, §6.5.3].

Comment: Hmm.. Thank you very much. So there is at least a 'high chance' that it works in 'good situations'. That is indeed good to know. Anyways, if anyone has an actual proof, it would be much appreciated if you could give a citation.  Thanks again.

Comment: There is a set-theoretic problem that may appear if your foundations aren't chosen carefully.  Waterhouse constructed a presheaf on affine schemes in the flat topology that has no sheafification.  Unsurprisingly, the same problem happens in the stack world.

Comment: What do you mean by foundations? Do you mean the site structure? If so, could we assume that for very good sites, this proposition would hold?

Comment: EDIT: Also since we are assuming that the associated stack already exists, would that difficulty still exists?

Comment: I think it should be fine, but I'm not a set theorist.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The three-step process is given as Theorem 3.8 in Ross Street, *Two dimensional sheaf theory*, J. Pure Appl. Algebra **23** (1982) 251–270 under some smallness assumptions.  Without some smallness hypotheses, you may run into set-theoretic problems.  For example, Waterhouse produced a presheaf with no flat sheafification for Theorem 5.5 in *Basically bounded functors and flat sheaves* Pac. J. Math. **57** no. 2 (1975) 597-610.

There is a one-step process using hypercovers instead of covers.  As Zhen Lin mentioned in a comment, this is discussed in the beginning of section 6.5.3 in Lurie's *Higher Topos Theory*.

Comment: Thank you very much (can't yet upvote, but will when i can :) ). I will have a look at that paper, but I think this should answer my question.