# Do isomorphisms spread out under suitable assumptions?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, stacks

I'm still trying to wrap my head around the "pathological" algebraic space $\mathbb{A}^1/\mathbb{Z}$; see [Questions about the algebraic space $\mathbb{A}^1/\mathbb{Z}$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/285183/questions-about-the-algebraic-space-mathbba1-mathbbz) and [Why is this not an algebraic space?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/9043/why-is-this-not-an-algebraic-space?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Let's put ourselves in a more general situation.

Let $X$ and   $Y$ be finite type algebraic stacks over Spec $\mathbb{Z}$. Assume   that $Y_{\mathbb{Q}}$ is isomorphic to $X_{\mathbb{Q}}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Is there an etale open $U =$ Spec $O_{K,S}$ of Spec $\mathbb{Z}$ such that $X$ and $Y$ are isomorphic over $U$?

I think the answer is negative, but I can't see how to construct a counterexample. The usual spreading out results in the literature require "finite presentation", and $X$ is not necessarily of finite presentation over $\mathbb{Z}$ (nor $\mathbb{Q}$).