# about the fppf-hom sheaf $\mathscr{H}om(X,\mathbb{G}_a)$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $T$ be the torus over $\mathbb{Q}$ defined by the equation $x^2+y^2=1$, then it becomes isomorphic to $\mathbb{G}_m$ over field $\mathbb{Q}[i]$. Let $X$ denote the character group of $T$, regarded as a locally constant sheaf for the etale topology or the fppf topology over $\mathrm{Spec}\mathbb{Q}$.

Now let's work in the fppf site of $\mathrm{Spec}\mathbb{Q}$, consider the Hom sheaf $\mathscr{H}om(X,\mathbb{G}_a)$, it seems for me that:

1. this sheaf has trivial global sections;
2. it becomes isomorphic to $\mathbb{G}_a$ over $\mathrm{Spec}\mathbb{Q[i]}$,

My questions are 
1. Is this sheaf represented by a group scheme?

1. If the answer to 1 is no, is it representable by an algebraic space (something like $\mathbb{G}_a/(\mathbb{Z}/2)$)?
2. If it is indeed something like $\mathbb{G}_a/(\mathbb{Z}/2)$ ,

how to compute the fppf-cohomology of the algebraic space associated to an action of a finite group on a group scheme? e.g. $H^1_{\mathrm{fppf}}(\mathbb{Q},\mathscr{H}om(X,\mathbb{G}_a))$

Comment: It is not a group scheme since there are no nontrivial forms of G_a. For algebraic spaces, see http://mathoverflow.net/questions/8918/is-an-algebraic-space-group-always-a-scheme

Comment: Thanks! Is the sheaf $\mathscr{H}om(X,\mathbb{G}_a)$ isomorphic to the algebraic space associated to the action of Z/2Z on $\mathbb{G}_a$? Do you have any idea for computing the first cohomology group of this sheaf (e.g. torsioness)?

Comment: Didn't I already answer the first question? For the cohomology, use the cover $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb Q(i))\to\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb Q)$.