# Representability of sheaves of groups

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, representable-functors

There are lots of natural functors (that define sheaves in the fppf topology) that are not representable by schemes. For example, hilbert schemes of proper non-projective schemes in general need algebraic spaces. However, I know of no examples of such subtleties with group schemes. Every sheaf of groups that I know of is already representable.

Is this a consequence of general theorems? Is it considered easier to show that a sheaf of groups (in the fppf topology) is representable by a scheme than a sheaf of sets? For example, are necessary and sufficient criteria known for a sheaf of groups in the fppf topology to be representable. How about for sheaves of abelian groups?

Comment: It is easier to show that a sheaf of groups is representable than a sheaf of sets --- see for example Matsumura, Hideyuki; Oort, Frans. Representability of group functors, and automorphisms of algebraic schemes. Invent. Math. 4 1967 1--25.

Comment: See also http://mathoverflow.net/questions/8918/ for a related question.

Answer (score 7):

I disagree with the premise of your question.  There are many natural non-representable sheaves of groups.  For example, the formal additive group $\widehat{\mathbb{G}_a}$ is a sheaf, as the colimit of (the sheaves represented by) spectra of $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^n)$, but it is not representable as a scheme.

I suspect your experience is a result of mathematicians being generally more likely to encounter group sheaves that are given by quasicoherent sheaves of finite type Hopf algebras, than by weird moduli functors.

Comment: I fully agree with this remark.

Answer (score 6):

For a functor with values in abelian groups there are nice representability criteria. Specifically, in the paper

Murre, J. P.:
On contravariant functors from the category of pre-schemes over a field into the category of abelian groups (with an application to the Picard functor). 
*Inst. Hautes Études Sci. Publ. Math.*, No. **23**, 1964, pp. 5–43.

the author gives a list of (7) conditions that ensure representability. Notice that conditions P4 & P5 just say that your functor is a fpqc sheaf.

Comment: http://archive.numdam.org/ARCHIVE/PMIHES/PMIHES_1964__23_/PMIHES_1964__23__5_0/PMIHES_1964__23__5_0.pdf